# Does D3.js conicConformal projection support the same clipping/trimming options as Matlab?

Tags: d3.js

I am attempting to replace Matlab's MappingToolbox with D3.js.  I am having difficulty reproducing Matlab's "Lambert Conformal Conic Projection" with D3's conicConformal.

I can't figure out how to clip/trim the D3 version to match what matlab does by default.  [See the example image here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/lambertstd.html).  I need to be able to trim out the "pie wedge" as well as trim at a given latitude.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Bostock added this for me.

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1e32984cf0587a86c806779a5464b0cc/0a72166e9f26ea44ed4c641f4371fd92fa237e52

Thanks Mike!

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? If so it's a very poor one. Please explain what this is and how it solves your problem.

Comment: This a new projection that Mr. Bostock added to the D3 mapping library.  It supports the clipping/trimming options that I needed in order to mimic the Matlab Version.

Comment: If you could edit that information into the answer, that would help.